# Reset scatter chart's node color in a mouse-clicked event

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, scatter-plot

I made this code that creates a scatter chart and allows me to change the color of a node on the plot when I click/select it.

```
 package com.jpc.javafx.charttest;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CreateChart extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  

//-------Create Chart--------------
      NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
      NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
      
      XYChart.Series<Number,Number> dataSeries1 = new XYChart.Series();
      ScatterChart chart = new ScatterChart(xAxis,yAxis); 
      
      dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data( 1, 567));
      dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data( 5, 612));
      dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 800));

      chart.getData().add(dataSeries1);

   //-----Select node and change color -----

      for(final XYChart.Data<Number,Number> data : dataSeries1.getData()) { 
          data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(e-> {
          //dataSeries1.getNode().lookup(".chart-symbol").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red"); that does not work 
          data.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue" );
      });
      }

      VBox vbox = new VBox(chart);

      Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 200);

      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setHeight(300);
      primaryStage.setWidth(1200);

      primaryStage.show();
  }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I select another point the previous one stays blue. So I need to reset all the nodes to the default color before I change the selected point's color.
I tried to add this:

`dataSeries1.getNode().lookup(".chart-symbol").setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");`

but I get:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I’m not really sure how to do that as it would need data in the plot or should i have just show the mouse  event part ?

Comment: ok I changed it to something that runs on it's own. Is that ok ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize your requirement:

- a visual property of a chart-symbol should be marked on user interaction
- there should be only one such marked symbol

Sounds like a kind of selection mechanism - which is not supported for chart symbols out of the box, application code must take care of it. The task is

- keep track of the (last) selected symbol
- guarantee that at any time only a single symbol is selected
- keep the visual state of un/selected as needed

The most simple implementation for the logic (the first two bullets) would be to keep a reference to the current selected and update it on user interaction. An appropriate instrument for the latter would be a PseudoClass: can be defined in the css and de/activated along with the logic.

Code snippets (to be inserted into your example)

```
// Pseudo-class
private PseudoClass selected = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected");
// selected logic
private Node selectedSymbol;

protected void setSelectedSymbol(Node symbol) {
    if (selectedSymbol != null) {
        selectedSymbol.pseudoClassStateChanged(selected, false);
    }
    selectedSymbol = symbol;
    if (selectedSymbol != null) {
        selectedSymbol.pseudoClassStateChanged(selected, true);
    }
}

// event handler on every symbol
data.getNode().setOnXX(e -> setSelectedSymbol(data.getNode()));
```

css example, to be loaded via a style-sheet f.i.:

```
.chart-symbol:selected {
   -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That works great !! Would I be able to use the same concept for selecting and unselecting multiple points ? Like create a list of nodes that have to be changed ( or have been changed ) ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it not be possible? And what happened when you tried :) Adjust the logic as needed - when getting too complex, separate the visual change from the logic (here in the simple case it's done at in one, you might implement a full fledged selection model or a TransformationList and listen to its changes to update the visuals)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is loop through the data and change the color for the one clicked and set all the other to `null`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CreateChart extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  

//-------Create Chart--------------
      NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
      NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
      
      XYChart.Series<Number,Number> dataSeries1 = new XYChart.Series();
      ScatterChart chart = new ScatterChart(xAxis,yAxis); 
      
      dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data( 1, 567));
      dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data( 5, 612));
      dataSeries1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 800));

      chart.getData().add(dataSeries1);

   //-----Select node and change color -----

      for(final XYChart.Data<Number,Number> data : dataSeries1.getData()) { 
          data.getNode().setOnMouseClicked(e-> {
          for(final XYChart.Data<Number,Number> data2 : dataSeries1.getData()) {
              if(data == data2)
              {
                    data2.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue" );
              }
              else
              {
                  data2.getNode().setStyle(null);
              }
          }
      });
      }

      VBox vbox = new VBox(chart);

      Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 200);

      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.setHeight(300);
      primaryStage.setWidth(1200);

      primaryStage.show();
  }
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I was expecting there was a way to change all the points at once. Like when you setup the graph with css.